# How to change the default positioning of Angular HTML files from "left-to-right" to "right-to-left"?

Tags: html, angular, right-to-left

I am interested to know if there is a way to change the default positioning of Angular HTML files from "left-to-right" to "right-to-left"?

If there isn't a way for that, what is the best way to do it?

I want when I create my HTML views on the position of the elements from right-to-left.

Comment: I think you are looking for  direction of contents , you can just use regular html   `dir="ltr"` or `dir="rtl"`

Comment: @JoelJoseph: Thank you. I think it's what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your parent html element, you could use `CSS flexbox layout` with `flex-direction: row-reverse`.

```
.container {
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

Please consult https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ for excellent detailed information about CSS flexbox layout.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. You need to set the [direction attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/dir): `dir="textDir"`

Where `textDir` can have the following values:

> - ltr, which means left to right and is to be used for languages that    are written from the left to the right (like English);
> - rtl, which means right to left and is to be used for languages that are written    from the right to the left (like Arabic);
> - auto, which lets the user    agent decide. It uses a basic algorithm as it parses the characters    inside the element until it
>     finds a character with a strong    directionality, then applies that
>     directionality to the whole    element.

Example:

```html
<p dir="rtl">This paragraph is in English but incorrectly goes right to left.</p>
<p dir="ltr">This paragraph is in English and correctly goes left to right.</p>

<hr>

<p>هذه الفقرة باللغة العربية ولكن بشكل خاطئ من اليسار إلى اليمين.</p>
<p dir="auto">هذه الفقرة باللغة العربية ، لذا يجب الانتقال من اليمين إلى اليسار.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

import flexLayoutModule in your module.

import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';

---

`<div dir="ltr" fxLayoutGap="20px">`        for Left align .

---

`<div dir="rtl" fxLayoutGap="20px">`           for right align.

For More Details,visit

[https://tburleson-layouts-demos.firebaseapp.com/#/docs][1]